# Sharepoint Form Datetime fields height&width

Tags: datepicker

I have SharePoint custom form with jquery tabs for some reason the sharepoint datefield is so small you can't see it even though it has width specified width. It shows as a small box about the size of a checkbox. I copied just the specific section from the form.aspx file. I am using jquery tabs. Request Date is the field in question.

```
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowedit">
    <xsl:param name="Pos" select="position()"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div id="hometab">
        <ul><li><a href="#RequiredInformation"><span>Required Information</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#ManagersApproval"><span>Manager&apos;s Approval</span></a></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="RequiredInformation">
        <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Title<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                            </nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Request Date<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                            </nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Request_x0020_Date" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Request_x0020_Date')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="Request_x0020_Date" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>User Name<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                            </nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="User_x0020_Name" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@User_x0020_Name')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="User_x0020_Name" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Job Title<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                            </nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Job_x0020_Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff4',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Job_x0020_Title')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff4description{$Pos}" FieldName="Job_x0020_Title" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Location<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                            </nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff5{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Location" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff5',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Location')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff5description{$Pos}" FieldName="Location" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Division<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                            </nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff6{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Division" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff6',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Division')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff6description{$Pos}" FieldName="Division" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this posting while searching for the answer to the same problem and since it had not been answered I continued searching until I found this:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sharepoint-2010-date-form-field-size-issue-when-used-in-jquery-ui-tab

Essentially, you need to edit the redmond CSS file that you download from jQuery and locate:

```
.ui-widget input,.ui-widget select,.ui-widget textarea,.ui-widget button{font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1em}
```

then change it to (or some other font size):

```
.ui-widget input,.ui-widget select,.ui-widget textarea,.ui-widget button{font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px}
```